# Sql Server Query Get Max count and add 1 to the count respect to the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query is working fine, but I need little modification in this what I am doing I getting value from 2 different tables.

From **TableA1** i am getting **Maxid** and from **TableB2** i am getting **Name** and **User**

The data i am getting like this

[image]

but I need the data like this look UserLastid which is increased respect to the row's in the table it is ok if we need to add extra column
Can you please help me to modify the query so i get the data like below image

[image]

```
SELECT name,user,
( SELECT MAX([id]) AS LastID FROM TableA1) as UserLastid
FROM   (SELECT name,user,
               Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY user) rn
        FROM   TableB2) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: What column defines the order, `user`? You seem to already know `row_number()`. So why aren't you just adding a `row_number()` to the the ID?

Comment: Thanks @stickybit for your reply!  I have no idea to how to add that i am totally new to Sql this was previous query which i am trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann add the `row_number()` to the ID. Assuming, that `user` is the column, that defines the order, that could look like:

```
SELECT name,
       user,
       (SELECT max(id)
               FROM tablea1)
       + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY user) userlastid
       FROM (SELECT name,
                    user,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                                       ORDER BY user) rn
                    FROM tableb2) t
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

The use of `row_number()` in the inner query however seems to complicated to me. I think, unless I'm missing something (sample data and desired results would have helped), you could simply go with an aggregation after all:

```
SELECT name,
       min(user) user,
       (SELECT max(id)
               FROM tablea1)
       + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY min(user)) userlastid
       FROM tableb2
       GROUP BY name;
```

---

Edit:

Using `coalesce()` to get `1` in case of an empty `tablea1`.

```
SELECT name,
       user,
       coalesce((SELECT max(id)
                        FROM tablea1), 1)
       + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY user) userlastid
       FROM (SELECT name,
                    user,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                                       ORDER BY user) rn
                    FROM tableb2) t
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

```
SELECT name,
       min(user) user,
       coalesce((SELECT max(id)
                        FROM tablea1), 1)
       + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY min(user)) userlastid
       FROM tableb2
       GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks :)

Comment: can you please add one validation in the query when tablea1 is null take the max  count as 1 and add after that Thanks

Comment: @ZCoder: Not sure I get what you want. See my edit if I guessed right. Otherwise please ask a new question explaining what the problem is in detail.